# Doing more than one copying/moving between usb and HD is very slow and slows down entire computer

Tags: usb

I've been looking around for an answer to my problem but I can't find anything. My problem is that I recently bought a new computer, Lenovo G500, it has 2xUSB3 and 1xUSB2, Intel pentium I3 2.4 GHz x4 and 6 Gib memory, it came with windows 8 but I removed it and installed Ubuntu 14.04.

The problem is, if, lets say, I try to **copy one** folder/file (doesn't matter the size) from/to my hard drive from/to the usb device, I have a WD 1tb usb 3 external HD but it does it with usb pens or another HD I have, it will copy fine, with high speeds. However, **if I was to start a second** copy/transfer while the first one is still going it will make the copying speed for both actions almost come to a stand still and take several hours.

This is not the only problem, the other problem is that while the copying is going on if I open any windows or programs they will take a very long time (may be up to 1 min) to open/start.

If I open the system monitoring it tells me that only 10% (+ or -) CPU usage, so memory is not an issue.

Any ideas what could be going on?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on a laptop was to change the disk scheduler.  This can be cone in three ways:

Test it by typing at the command line (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

`echo cfq | sudo tee /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler`

and replace "sda" with the device name of your devices.  Do this for both of your disks.  You can check what scheduler is in use by entering

`cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler`

reboot to revert to standard if this does not work.

To make the changes permanent, place the command into /etc/rc.local or add a kernal option `elevator=cfq`

[more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009577/selecting-a-linux-i-o-scheduler)

---

Since I wrote this answer, I have changed my strategy.  I now user the cfq disk scheduler, but have added the 'noautogroup' flag to my boot parameters.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it later (as I'm in a different computer right now) and get back to you with the outcome.

Comment: Ok, I finally I had a small break from work and I managed to do this. Unfortunately it didn't work it tells me straight away:bash: /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler: Permission denied, any suggestions what would that be? It doesn't even give me the chance to put my administrator password.

Comment: Sorry - the command should be started with sudo---  `sudo cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler`

Comment: Hi; the second command was fine, that one told me noop [deadline] cfq, is the first command you put in the orignial answer: sudo echo cfq > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler that tells me despite sudo: bash: /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler: Permission denied

Comment: Ah - I always have trouble with sudo and echo - what you can do instead is type `sudo -i` which will run sudo as a shell, then type `echo cfq > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler` within the shell to get the command to run.  You will need to type `exit` to leave the shell, and `exit` again to close the terminal

Comment: Hi Charles; Sorry that my response time is not the fastest. So I tried the first solution you told me, it seems to improve things slightly, but not great. I don't think I feel confident enough to deal with the noautogroup boot parameter. I saw in another forum that it can cause problems with the booting. Thanks for your help.